# Two values from an array checkbox

Tags: php, mysql

So I have a mysql table for the charges of a hospital. My program currently only gets the price of the checked procedure. But now, I also want to get the procedure name when it is checked.

transaction.php

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
     echo ' <tr> <td>'.$row[0].'</td> <td>'.$row[1].'</td><td>'.$row[2].'</td>';
     $procedure=$row['procedure'];
     echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="er[]" value="$price."|".$procedure"></td>';
     echo "</tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

computation.php

```
  <?php
      if(isset($_POST['er']))
      {
        $ercharge=$_POST['er'];
        $totalofer = array_sum($ercharge);  
      }
      if(isset($_POST['ultrasound']))
      {
        $x=$_POST['ultrasound'];
        $totalofultrasound =  array_sum($x);
      }
      if(isset($_POST['confinement']))
      {
        $y=$_POST['confinement'];
        $totalofconfinement =  array_sum($y);
      }
      $total = $totalofer + $totalofultrasound + $totalofconfinement;
      $p = explode("|", $ercharge);
      echo $p;
      echo  $total;
?>
```

It only gets the row for price. Can the value attribute have two values? I can't just make another checkbox cause that would be inappropriate.

edit: the explode function doesnt work. It says: Warning: explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\computation.php on line 18

Comment: It's an array because of how it is being submitted: <input type="checkbox" name="er[]" value="$price."|".$procedure"> - Are there multiple checkboxes named "er[]"? If there is only one, change it to just "er", otherwise you will need to step through the array and process each individually.

Comment: Passing two values under the same parameter is a bad practice, if you want to do something like that your design is probably not good and most chances are that it will cause maintenance issues in the future.

Comment: Does the price vary? If not, it would be simpler to just pass in the procedure's ID, and then retrieve the procedure and price info on the computation.php page. Also, explode returns an array.

Comment: @EricBrandel Nope. Just that one since its on a loop. If I change it to just "er", you can only just check one procedure. It wouldnt compute multiple checks.

Comment: @EricBrandel Yes. The prices vary.

Comment: @alfasin Is there any other way then?

Comment: @user1551672 yes, pass two different parameters ;)

Comment: @alfasin Yes i did that. I tried separating the procedure name into a hidden one. But it doesnt get the value and instead just outputs the word "Array".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split your parameters in the HTML:

```
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="checked[$row_index][]" value="1">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="prices[$row_index][]" value="$price">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="procedures[$row_index][]" value="$procedure"></td>';
```

where `$row_index` is incremented on each row (`tr` tag)

By the way, explode will work on the items of the er array, not on the array itself. Try:

```
foreach ($er as $item) {
  var_dump( explode( "|", $item ) );
}
```

Comment: Ok i changed it to:
`echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="er[]" value="'.$price.'">';
   echo '<input type="hidden" name="procedures[]" value="'.$procedure.'"></td>';
   echo "</tr>";`

the total is computed now. So the price works fine. The problem is the procedure name. It only shows: "Array".

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question but couldn't you set the name attrtibute for your checkbox to the name of the procedure?  It looks like you are setting the name to the er[] array but you never reference that later.

Comment: I can't do that since its on a loop and is retrieved from a mysql table. I referenced er[] to the computation.php so it could output multiple values if there are many checks in the form.